# aws s3 sync doesn't download the file and instead create an empty directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The question was originally posted on Super User (https://superuser.com/questions/1768933/aws-sync-doesnt-download-the-file-and-instead-create-an-empty-directory), but with no answers. I thought stack overflow, although not officially designed for this type of question, could really help given the huge amount of experts here.

The file I'm trying to download is:

```
s3://ont-open-data/gm24385_q20_2021.10/analysis/20210805_1713_5C_PAH79257_0e41e938/guppy_5.0.15_sup/align_unfiltered/chr19/calls2ref.bam
```

This is an open dataset. I followed the tutorial here: https://labs.epi2me.io/tutorials/.
The command I used was:

```
aws s3 sync --no-sign-request s3://ont-open-data/gm24385_q20_2021.10/analysis/20210805_1713_5C_PAH79257_0e41e938/guppy_5.0.15_sup/align_unfiltered/chr19/calls2ref.bam destination.bam
```

However, instead of downloading the file, aws simply created an empty directory named `destination.bam`, which makes no sense...

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.15.15 Python/3.6.10 Linux/4.4.0-210-generic botocore/1.10.15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the fact that `calls2ref.bam` is not a directory.

If you list the `chr19/` directory, it returns:

```
2021-10-07 00:57:41        228 basecall_stats.log
2021-10-07 00:57:42 1033176198 calls2ref.bam
2021-10-07 00:58:33     507904 calls2ref.bam.bai
2021-10-07 00:58:33   15443858 calls2ref_stats.txt
2021-10-07 00:58:35          0 extract_region_from_bam.log
```

The `cp` command works because you have provided the full Key of an object that you wish to copy. The `sync` command, however, expects to receive a **directory** and it will copy the entire contents of the directory including sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't solve the problem with `sync`, but I realized that `cp` works! The following command downloaded the file:

```
aws s3 cp --no-sign-request s3://ont-open-data/gm24385_q20_2021.10/analysis/20210805_1713_5C_PAH79257_0e41e938/guppy_5.0.15_sup/align_unfiltered/chr19/calls2ref.bam destination.bam
```